# How to use !FindInMap in !Sub | userdata section of Cloudformation

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

How can I use !FindInMap in userdata section.
In the following userdata I want to update the MainSshKey with the mapping data.

```
Mappings:
    AccountToStage:
        "123456789012":
            StageName: Beta
    Beta:
      us-east-1:
        MainSshKey: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC
        AdminSshKey: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1
```

userdata:

```
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #cloud-config
          users:
          - name: main
            ssh_authorized_keys:
            - ${MainSshKey}
          - name: admin
            ssh_authorized_keys:
            - ${AdminSshKey}
```

this is what I have tried

```
          #cloud-config
          users:
          - name: main
            ssh_authorized_keys: 
            - ${MainSshKey}
            - MainSshKey: !FindInMap
                - !FindInMap
                  - AccountToStage
                  - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                  - StageName
               - !Ref "AWS::Region"
               - MainSshKey
          - name: admin
            ssh_authorized_keys:
            - ${AdminSshKey}
```

Cloudformation is not able to resolve this.

Note: If I defined MainSshKey as a parameter, and it works fine, doesn't seems to work using FindInMap

Any pointers are much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a list form of [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html). So your could should be something along these lines. Note that you will probably fix all the indentations and further change it to work. Nevertheless, the list form of `Sub` is the key to your issue.

```
        Fn::Base64: !Sub 
           - |
             #cloud-config
             users:
             - name: main
               ssh_authorized_keys:
               - ${SubMainSshKey}
             - name: admin
               ssh_authorized_keys:
               - ${AdminSshKey}
           - SubMainSshKey: !FindInMap
                - !FindInMap
                  - AccountToStage
                  - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                  - StageName
                - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - MainSshKey
```

ALso, this is incorrect userdata, so I'm not sure what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following, the plus tells it to keep a newline afterwards. Arg1 tells it to substitute the result of the Fn::FindInMap for the MainSshKey in arg0.

```
         Fn::Base64: !Sub
          - |+
            #cloud-config
            users:
            - name: main
              ssh_authorized_keys:
              - ${MainSshKey}
            - name: admin
              ssh_authorized_keys:
              - ${AdminSshKey}
          - MainSshKey:
              Fn::FindInMap:
                - !FindInMap
                  - AccountToStage
                  - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                  - StageName
                - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - MainSshKey
```

Also if you require substituting two values (example: MainSshKey and AdminSshKey), you can use the same list Sub construct example below.

```
         Fn::Base64: !Sub
          - |+
            #cloud-config
            users:
            - name: main
              ssh_authorized_keys:
              - ${MainSshKey}
            - name: admin
              ssh_authorized_keys:
              - ${AdminSshKey}
          - MainSshKey:
              Fn::FindInMap:
                - !FindInMap
                  - AccountToStage
                  - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                  - StageName
                - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - MainSshKey
            AdminSshKey:
              Fn::FindInMap:
                - !FindInMap
                  - AccountToStage
                  - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                  - StageName
                - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - AdminSshKey
```